# Django custom user model and registration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a Django application where I enabled login and registration with Tivix's django-rest-auth (https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth).

Now,

1. I want to have a custom user model with few additional fields
2. I want to be able to enable registration along with these additional fields.
3. Login would be done with email instead of username

What are the steps to achieve this? I went through answers, however I was confused with few things:

- The role of serializers here and custom user signUp form and whether I should have a signUp view as well?
- Custom user model from `AbstractBaseUser` or simply `User`of `django.contrib.auth.models`

I already tried to implement something and ran into an issue ([django-rest-auth custom registration fails to save extra fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841612/django-rest-auth-custom-registration-fails-to-save-extra-fields?noredirect=1#comment64169246_37841612)), so wanted to ask for a correct approach.

Comment: I did provide an answer to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38553202/1566605. So hopefully this one can be closed.

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841612/django-rest-auth-custom-registration-fails-to-save-extra-fields/38553202#38553202