# Override rest-auth signup to add extra fields to my backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to override the `RegisterSerializer` to add additional field that i could save on the backend while the signup process but i couldn't get it to work. I'm using React as a view layer and it passes the data perfectly when i use the default `RegisterSerializer` after adding `RegisterSerializerCustom` it doesn't work at all

here is my code :

```
    from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
    class RegisterSerializerCustom(RegisterSerializer):
        mobile = serializers.CharField(required=False, write_only=True)

        def get_cleaned_data(self):
            return {
                'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
                'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
                'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
                'mobile': self.validated_data.get('mobile', ''),
            }

        def validate_mobile(self, mobile):
            return mobile

        def save(self, request):
            res = super(RegisterSerializerCustom, serializers).save(request)
            return res
```

and i added my these in setting.py

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
'REGISTER_SERIALIZER':'user_profile.serializers.RegisterSerializerCustom',
}
```

what is the problem in my code ?!

Comment: You say it doesn't work at all - is there an error? What happens?

Comment: it doesn't run at all , like if it's not there , i found another path to do what i want but this issue is strange and i don't know what i did wrong

Comment: Please check out this thread, I think this is exactly your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841612/django-rest-auth-custom-registration-fails-to-save-extra-fields

Answer (score 2):

It must be registered in setting.py like this:

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
   'REGISTER_SERIALIZER':'user_profile.serializers.RegisterSerializerCustom',
}
```